# Get markdown heading level in awk

Tags: shell, parsing, awk, markdown, text-processing

Given a string with a markdown heading, what would be the best way to return the level of the heading in `awk`?

Assumptions:

- For this scenario, to be considered a heading the only requisite is that the line must start with a `#`
- The level of the heading is the number of `#`s before another character appears
- If the string is not a heading, the program should return nothing
- Must use `awk` not `gawk`

### Example 1

Input:

```markdown
# Heading
```

Expected output:

```
1
```

### Example 2

Input:

```markdown
## Heading
```

Expected output:

```
2
```

### Example 3

```markdown
## This is level #2
```

Expected output:

```
2
```

### Example 4

Example without a leading `#`s in the provided string

```markdown
This a normal paragraph with a # in the middle
```

Expected output:

### Example 5

Example with leading blank character

```markdown
 # Heading
```

Expected output:

### Example 6

Example with leading `\`

```markdown
\# Heading
```

Expected output:

### Example 7

```markdown
##Heading
```

Expected output:

```
2
```

### Attempts

I tried using `#` as separator (`FS`) and `NF` to count the number of fields, but (of course) it doesn't know if it's a `#` indicating heading level or an ordinary `#` that is part of the title text.

```bash
echo '## Heading 2' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="#"} /^#/{print NF-1}'
# Returns 2 (right)
```

```bash
echo '## This is level #2' | awk 'BEGIN{FS="#"} /^#/{print NF-1}'
# Returns 3 (wrong, should be 2)
```

I also tried with `gsub`, but to no avail (same problem):

```
echo '## Heading 2' | awk '/^#/{gsub(/[^#]/,""); print length;}'
# Returns 2 (right)
```

```
echo '## This is level #2' | awk '/^#/{gsub(/[^#]/,""); print length;}'
# Returns 3 (wrong, should be 2)
```

Any insights?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Yes, a tool like awk would be able to handle this, get the book Effective AWK Programming, 5th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how,

Comment: [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: @EdMorton edited and added a minimal reproducible example with testable sample input and expected output. Thanks!

Comment: @JoãoPesce I don't see it. I expected to see a multi-line block of text with `#`s in it as the sample output and then either an updated version of that with numbers attached somewhere or just a list of numbers or something else as the expected output.

Comment: @EdMorton I've now separated each of the examples in two code blocks each: input and expected output. Below there are also two attempts that you can run directly on shell with comments showing the returned output and the expected output. Let me know if you need more clarification. Cheers!

Comment: You're showing individual lines that match the "patterns" you want to match. It's always trivial to match what you expect and much harder to not match what you don't expect so your example should contain lines with `#`s in undesirable places (leading spaces? spaces between?), lines with no `#`s, etc. and the expected output should be a block of text that includes the numbers, not just numbers, so we can see if/how they should be intermixed with the input.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks for taking your time! I've now clarified that headings are considered only if they start with `#` and strings with no `#` (or that don't start with `#`) should not return anything. As already pointed out, output should be only the number, not intermixed with the input.

Comment: Are you saying your input is literally just 1 line of text at a time rather than a block of text that you want all the header lines in analyzed at once in 1 call to awk? If you're calling awk 1 line at a time in a shell loop - that's an anti-pattern.  To do what you're asking for here is just `awk 'match($0,/^#+/){print RLENGTH}'` but it's extremely unlikely that calling awk 1 line at a time is a reasonable approach.

Comment: @EdMorton `match` and `RLENGTH` works PERFECTLY, thanks! The scope of the complete problem is a lot bigger, but phrasing it as one line at a time makes it a focused minimal reproducible scenario. Exactly what I needed to solve the larger problem. In case you want to reopen & answer the question I will accept it as the valid answer. Thanks again for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is:

```
awk 'match($0,/^#+/){print RLENGTH}'
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
# Heading
## Heading
## This is level #2
Example without a leading #s in the provided string
This a normal paragraph with a # in the middle
 # Heading
\# Heading
##Heading
```

```
$ while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
    echo "$line" | awk 'match($0,/^#+/){print RLENGTH}'
done < file
# Heading
1
## Heading
2
## This is level #2
2
Example without a leading #s in the provided string
This a normal paragraph with a # in the middle
 # Heading
\# Heading
##Heading
2
```

Do not really call awk 1 line at a time like this though as it's extremely inefficient and error prone, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice), compared to just calling awk once:

```
$ awk '{print} match($0,/^#+/){print RLENGTH}' file
# Heading
1
## Heading
2
## This is level #2
2
Example without a leading #s in the provided string
This a normal paragraph with a # in the middle
 # Heading
\# Heading
##Heading
2
```